# How to make a background fit with his button dynamically ? [Android]

Tags: android, button, background

I want to add an image background to my buttons (which are added dyncamilly), but the image original size looks applied by default, and it is far too big. How can I adjust my image to fit with the button size automatically ?

```
Drawable img = act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.top);
button.setBackground(img);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ImageButton http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

They should handle the sizing automatically

Comment: I just tried it, replacing my Button by ImageButton but the original size also looks applied, instead of the default button size. –  Redtheone Towedance 9 mins ago

Comment: did you try Bidhan A's suggestion of setting the scaleType, use .setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER) ?

Comment: I added this line to my code with ImageButton, and nothing changed : 
    imgButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Button xml, try adding this

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: I haven't got xml, all is done dynamically. how can I do ? I just have a Button & a Drawable, no ImageView